# ASP.net RegularExpressionValidator allows postback even if the input is not valid

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, validation

I'm trying to make a form for uploading images. I've placed a `RegularExpressionValidator` to check the extension of the selected file.
Its `ValidationExpression` is :

`(?i:^.+(.jpg|.ttf|.png|.gif)$)`

But when i select an .exe file for example. The page does a postback and then shows me the error. And the .exe file is stored where it shouldn't.

Here's my HTML code for the control:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/filippo_admin_page/admin_master.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="a_gallery.aspx.cs" Inherits="photography.filippo_admin_page.a_gallery" %>
    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
        <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/a_gallery.css" />
    </asp:Content>
    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        <div id="whole_wrapper">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Insert new image:</legend>
                <div id="controls_wrapper">        
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <asp:Label AssociatedControlID="title_txt" runat="server" ID="title_lbl">Title:</asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="title_txt" runat="server" placeholder="Image title"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
                                ControlToValidate="title_txt" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" 
                                ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="gallery_validation">Required!</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <asp:Label AssociatedControlID="desc_txt" runat="server" ID="desc_lbl">Description:</asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="desc_txt" runat="server" placeholder="Image description" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <asp:Label AssociatedControlID="cat_txt" runat="server" ID="cat_lbl">Category:</asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="cat_txt" runat="server" placeholder="Image category"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" 
                                ControlToValidate="cat_txt" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" 
                                ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="gallery_validation">Required!</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <asp:Label ID="upload_lbl" runat="server">Select Image:</asp:Label>
                            <asp:FileUpload ID="upload_pnl" runat="server" />
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" 
                                ControlToValidate="upload_pnl" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" 
                                ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="gallery_validation">Required!</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" 
                                ControlToValidate="upload_pnl" ErrorMessage="RegularExpressionValidator" 
                                ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="(?i:^.+(.jpg|.ttf|.png|.gif)$)" 
                                ValidationGroup="gallery_validation">File must be an image.</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <asp:Button ID="clear" runat="server" Text="Clear" UseSubmitBehavior="False" />
                            <asp:Button ID="submit" runat="server" Text="Upload"  onclick="submit_Click" 
                                ValidationGroup="gallery_validation"/>                        
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <asp:Label ID="msg_lbl" Visible="false" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </fieldset>

        </div>    
    </asp:Content>
```

Here's the part of the validator:

```
<li>
    <asp:Label ID="upload_lbl" runat="server">Select Image:</asp:Label>
    <asp:FileUpload ID="upload_pnl" runat="server" />
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" 
        ControlToValidate="upload_pnl" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" 
        ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="gallery_validation">Required!</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" 
        ControlToValidate="upload_pnl" ErrorMessage="RegularExpressionValidator" 
        ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="(?i:^.+(.jpg|.ttf|.png|.gif)$)" 
        ValidationGroup="gallery_validation">File must be an image.</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
</li>
```

I have `ValidationGroup` equals `gallery_validation` and is set on all controls that i want to validate, including the `submit` button it self.

If you want the whole HTML code for the file just ask.

Comment: post the aspx markup please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is invalid, it cannot be processed properly on the client.  My IE9 shows error when I use the same regex.  If I switch it to a standard regex expression, everything works properly.  So, it is necessary to change the regex.  I will post it here shortly.

The problematic part here is - ?i: which is a part of the .NET Framework.  So, it does not work on the client side.  For more details, please refer to the

[make regular expression validator case insensitive?](http://forums.asp.net/t/1236947.aspx)

This link contains also a solution to the problem.

Comment: I've had major trouble with CustomValidator, and creating separate JavaScript and server-side validation seems too unwieldy. The answer @platon linked suggested just changing the regex to be inherently case insensitive, e.g. `^.+(.[jJ][pP[gG]|.[tT][tT][fF]|.[pP][nN][gG]|.[gG][iI][fF])$`. That seems the simplest route.

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable client script with **EnableClientScript="true"**

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator EnableClientScript="true"
ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" 
    ControlToValidate="upload_pnl" ErrorMessage="RegularExpressionValidator" 
    ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="(?i:^.+(.jpg|.ttf|.png|.gif)$)" 
    ValidationGroup="gallery_validation">File must be an image.</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

In addition, please note

*The regular-expression validation implementation is slightly different on the client than on the server. On the client, JScript regular-expression syntax is used. On the server, System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex syntax is used. Since JScript regular expression syntax is a subset of System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex syntax, it is recommended that JScript regular-expression syntax be used in order to yield the same results on both the client and the server.*

Your regex is not valid in Javascript. You have to change it.

Comment: the default value of the EnableClientScript property is true.  So, it should not be set declaratively.

Comment: Yes it's enabled by default.

Comment: @Cybermaxs hmmm, but how to fix it ?

Comment: You have to write a valid js regex. Your current regex contains groups and back ref which is only understood by c# regexes.